# Drag and drop functionality using qpageview in pyqt5

Tags: python, drag-and-drop, pyqt5

I am using `qpageview` (See [here](https://qpageview.org/qpageview.html) and [here](https://pypi.org/project/qpageview/)) in pyqt5 to create a document viewer which can view pdf, jpg, png, and, svg files as part of a bigger project. The code so far is as follows, which is just a window to open the pdf/jpg/png/svg file.

```
import sys
import os
import glob

from PyQt5.QtCore import QDir
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QMainWindow, QApplication, QMenu, QVBoxLayout,
    QWidget, QAction, QFileDialog)
from PyQt5.QtGui import (QIcon, QKeySequence)
import qpageview

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    
    """Main Window."""

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """Initializer."""

        super(MainWindow,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.window_title = 'Document Viewer'
        self.setWindowTitle(self.window_title)
        self.resize(600,450)

        widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        widget.setLayout(self.layout)

        self._createImageViewer()
        self._createMenu()

    def _createImageViewer(self):

        self.viewer = qpageview.View()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.viewer)
        self.viewer.show()

        return

    def _createMenu(self):
        self.file_menu  = self.menuBar().addMenu("&File")

        # File submenu
        self.openFileAction = QAction(QIcon.fromTheme('document-open'), 
            '&Open', self, shortcut = QKeySequence.Open, 
            triggered = self.openFile)
        self.file_menu.addAction(self.openFileAction)

    def openFile(self):
        fileName, _ = QFileDialog().getOpenFileName(self,
            "Open Documents", QDir.currentPath(), 
            "PDF (*.pdf)" 
            + ";;" + "PNG (*.png)"
            + ";;" + "JPEG (*.jpg *.jpeg)"
            + ";;" + "SVG (*.svg)"
            )

        if fileName:

            ext = os.path.splitext(fileName)[1]

            if ext == '.pdf':
                self.viewer.loadPdf(fileName)

            elif ext == '.jpg' or ext == '.jpeg' or ext == '.png':
                self.viewer.loadImages(glob.glob(fileName))
                
            elif ext == '.svg':
                self.viewer.loadSvgs(glob.glob(fileName))
                
            self.viewer.setViewMode(qpageview.FitWidth)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MainWindow()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

However, I also require drag and drop functionality where the image files (png/jpg) can be dragged from this application to another external application. I know how to do this using `QLabel()` and I know this kind of functionality is also available for `qpageview` using `QDrag` (See [here](https://qpageview.org/export.html)). However, I am not an expert and do not know how to proceed. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If you know how to do it with QLabel, it shouldn't be that different for that viewer. You will probably need to subclass `qpageview.View` and override the `mouseMoveEvent`.

Comment: @musicamante: I had already tried to do it. But unfortunately, I don't know how to get the `pixmap` and `mimedata` info `qpageview.View` and thus have been unable to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I finally managed to drag a png image to another external application. So just after the `openFile(self)` function (see my original question), I added the following two functions and now it works. I also had to add `from qpageview.export import ImageExporter` at the top where I am importing modules.

```
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.drag_start_position = event.pos()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if not (event.buttons() & Qt.LeftButton):
            return

        if (event.pos() - self.drag_start_position).manhattanLength() < QApplication.startDragDistance():
            return

        page = self.viewer.currentPage()
        if page:
            exporter = ImageExporter(page)
            mimedata = exporter.mimeData()
            exporter.drag(self,mimedata)
```